# Suppressing and adding parameters for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an ajax call for two separate click events. The difference is for the second click event the variable testOne should not be part of the call and instead there would be a new variable. How should I approach this?

```
var varOne = '';
var varTwo = '';
var varThree = '';

function testAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://someblabla.php",
        data: {
            testOne: varOne,
            testTwo: varOne
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}

$('.clickOne').click(function(){
    varOne = 'xyz123';
    varTwo = '123hbz';
    testAjax();
});   

$('.clickTwo').click(function(){
    //varOne = 'xyz123'; // I dont need this for this click
    varTwo = '123hbz';
    varThree = 'kjsddfag'; // this gets added
    testAjax();
});

<div class="clickOne"></div>
<div class="clickTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some like this

```
function testAjax(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://someblabla.php",
        data: data,
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}

$('.clickOne').click(function(){
    var data= { 
    varOne: 'xyz123',
    varTwo: '123hbz',
}
    testAjax(data);
});   

$('.clickTwo').click(function(){
    var data= { 
    varThree : 'kjsddfag',
    varTwo: '123hbz',
}
    testAjax(data);
});

<div class="clickOne"></div>
<div class="clickTwo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the same in other way with minimum line of code, you can call the ajax on click event and pass the data based on the element triggered the click event.
like this:

```
$('.ajax').click(function(e){
 if($(this).hasClass('clickOne')){
  var data= {     varOne: 'xyz123';    varTwo: '123hbz'; }
 }else{
  var data= {     varThree : 'kjsddfag';    varTwo: '123hbz'; } 
 }
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "http://someblabla.php",
  data: data,
 }).done(function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
 });
 e.preventDefault();
});
<div class="ajax clickOne"></div>
<div class="ajax clickTwo"></div>
```

In this way you can put as many conditions for different data variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing it like this:

```
function testAjax(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://someblabla.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}

$('.clickOne').click(function(){
    var data {
        varOne = 'xyz123',
        varTwo = '123hbz'
    }
    testAjax(data);
});   

$('.clickTwo').click(function(){
    var data = {
        varTwo = '123hbz',
        varThree = 'kjsddfag'
     }
    testAjax(data);
});

<div class="clickOne"></div>
<div class="clickTwo"></div>
```

This way you absolute control over which variables are added to which ajax call. You should not use global variables unless you really need them to be global, which doesn't seem to be the case.

You can pass whatever JavaScript object to the `data` parameter of the `ajax` method.

Comment: can you please share some code sample? I kinda know what you are saying but getting a bit lost at the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something.  I often hide value inside the value attribute of the button tags to produce something like this.

I haven't been able to test this of course but I thought it was worth mentioning.

jquery:

```
var fields = '';

function testAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://someblabla.php",
        data: fields
    }).done(function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
        });
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
    var varCount = 0;
    var vars = $(this).val().split('|');
    $.each( vars, function( key, value ) {
        varCount++;
        fields = fields + 'var' + varCount + '=' + value + '&';
    });
    fields = fields.slice(0,-1);
    $(this).val('123hbz|kjsddfag');
    testAjax();
});
```

html:

```
<button id="btn" value="xyz123|123hbz"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized and cleaner version -

```
var varTwo='junk1'
var varOne='junk2'
var varThree='junk3'

function testAjax(data){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        url: "http://someblabla.php",
        data: data,
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}

$('.ajaxClick').click(function(){
    var data={};
    if(this.classList.contains('clickOne')){
        data.varOne=varOne;
        data.varTwo=varTwo;
    }else{
        data.varThree=varThree;
        data.varTwo=varTwo;
    }
    testAjax(data);

});   
<div class="ajaxClick clickOne"></div>
<div class="ajaxClick clickTwo"></div>
```

Comment: The only issue I have in adding the ajax class to the divs and then looking for them is the scalability. If I do it this way then I would have to maintain it little bit more. But this is a very good solution actually